# UTC DateTime Conversion in multilingual site from string value

Tags: c#, string, datetime, type-conversion, sitefinity

i need to save UTC current time in database in encrypted string and while i am getting data decrypt it and convert to date-time again.

Problem is that datetime in Arabic culture is Some thing like this **"12/05/35 09:40:45 ص"**
and in english culture like **"12/05/35 09:40:45 AM"**

When i try to convert it from string to DateTime it gives an error that given string is not valid string for conversion.

i used culture formate in conversion like that

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Helper.Decrypt(dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("LastLoginDate"))), new CultureInfo("ar-AE"))
```

this works fine for once but after some time again not valid string error.
might be possible that it is not correct way or our testing problem.

Can you please suggest any better solution except to trim datetime string before conversion like this.

Comment: "i need to save UTC current time in database in encrypted string" - why? Even if you need to encrypt it for some reason, there's no need to store it as a culture-sensitive string. Is there any reason why you're not just keeping it as a datetime field in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture:

```
string str = Helper.Decrypt(dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("LastLoginDate")));
DateTime result;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(str, out result))
   result = DateTime.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```